# Understanding proof of "The ring of integers of a number field is a Dedekind domain"

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

Let K be a number field and $O_K$ its ring of integers.

Trying to understand proof of "The ring of integers of a number field is a Dedekind domain", in the part:

**Every element of the finitely generated abelian group $O_K /p$ is killed by $a_0$ , so $O_K /p$ is a finite set**. What does it mean?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: You quoted two sentences. What exactly do you not understand?

Comment: Please check the sentence in bold, how does $a_0$ kill the elements in $O_K/p$ and why $O_K/p$  is a finite set.Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

$a_0$ is a nonzero integer, and $a_0(\mathcal O_K/\mathfrak p)=0$, that is
$\mathfrak{p}\supseteq|a_0|\mathcal{O}_K$ and so $\mathcal O_K/\mathfrak p$
is a quotient of $\mathcal O_K/|a_0|\mathcal O_K$. Therefore $|\mathcal O_K/\mathfrak p|\le|\mathcal O_K/|a_0|\mathcal O_K|$.
But $|\mathcal O_K/|a_0|\mathcal O_K|=|a_0|^n<\infty$, where $n=|K:\Bbb Q|$
since as an Abelian group, $\mathcal O_K$ is free of rank $n$.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know if $|\mathcal O_K/|a_0|\mathcal O_K|=|a_0|^n$ is always true? how do we get that result? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

$a_0$ kills the elements of $\mathcal O_K/\mathfrak p$ simply because the author has just explained why $a_0 \in \mathfrak p$.

On the other hand,  $\mathcal O_K/\mathfrak p$ is a finitely generated abelian group, and the above remark shows it is torsion, which implies finiteness, by the *Structure theorem for finitely generated abelian groups*.